# Can you change difficulty mid-playthrough in Danganronpa?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

At the start of Danganronpa on Android I'm asked to pick a difficulty level for Logic and Action. Is it possible to change the difficulty mid-playthrough after starting?

[image]